# Dynamic Linq Expression for multi-level query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following Linq expression that I would like to build dynamically.

The problem i'm running into is that I can't build the expression tree to accommodate the complex Select/Any statements.  I have read that in order to use methods you literally have to invoke the method as in:

```
 Invoke("Any")
```

---

Expression that I need built dynamically:

```
Expression<Func<TXLifeRequest, bool>> filter = (txreq) => 
txreq.IsDeleted == false &&
txreq.OLifE.Holding.Select(h => h.Policy)
    .Any(p => p.RequirementInfo
        .Any(r => r.ReqStatus.tc == OLI_LU_REQSTAT.OLI_REQSTAT_OUTSTANDING.tc));

var results = db.GetQueryable(filter)
                .Include(r => r.OLifE.Holding.Select(h => h.Policy)
                   .Select(p => p.RequirementInfo)).ToList();
```

Here are my model classes:

**OLI_LU_REQSTAT**

```
public partial class OLI_LU_REQSTAT : BaseType {

    public string tc { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

**TXLifeRequest**

```
public partial class TXLifeRequest : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual OLifE OLifE { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

---

**OLifE**

```
public partial class OLifE : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual List<Holding> Holding { get; set; }
        ...
}
```

---

**Holding**

```
public class Holding : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual Policy Policy { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

---

**Policy**

```
public class Policy : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual List<RequirementInfo> RequirementInfo { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

---

**RequirementInfo**

```
public partial class RequirementInfo : BaseEntity
{
     public virtual OLI_LU_REQSTAT ReqStatus { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

---

Currently I am running a reflection foreach against GetProperty but have not been able to understand the documentation in order to get 3-4 levels down in the object model:

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "i");
MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(val, propertyType);


var condition =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            property,
            constant
        ),
        parameter
    );

result = AppendExpression(result, condition, result);
```

---

**Update 1.)** Added RequirementInfo. Adding all class properties would not make sense as the required class structure is there.

Comment: I would suggest to name your properties and classes in more detail for this post since it is hard to understand and follow what you need if no domain knowledge is there :)

Comment: @Andre - I'm not sure I follow. The domain is just a semantic, it's mostly how to build the multi-tier expression dynamically where Lists need traversed.

Comment: @ChuckD `var superman = carrot + love` This code doesn't really describe what it does. `var salaryAfterRaise = previousSalary + raise` This is a lot clearer. Functionally, this second code snippet is exactly the same, but the naming makes it a lot easier to understand for people who are new to the code. Understand that us readers have to learn your code by reading it. You already know what you want your code to do, but we don't.

Comment: carrot + love absolutely makes sence to me!

Comment: You skipped the `RequirementInfo` class

Comment: @xanatos - Added the last class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite long. I feel it is too much complex to be "maintainable", and if you need to do some changes, it becomes quite difficult. Even making it "dynamic" so that it can be controlled (enabling or disabling parts) is difficult.

Given

```
// Enumerable.Any()
static readonly MethodInfo anyTSource = (from x in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                         where x.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Any)
                                         let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
                                         where args.Length == 1
                                         let pars = x.GetParameters()
                                         where pars.Length == 2 &&
                                             pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(args[0]) &&
                                             pars[1].ParameterType == typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(args[0], typeof(bool))
                                         select x).Single();

// Enumerable.Select()
public static readonly MethodInfo selectTSourceTResult = (from x in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                                          where x.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Select)
                                                          let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
                                                          where args.Length == 2
                                                          let pars = x.GetParameters()
                                                          where pars.Length == 2 &&
                                                                    pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(args[0]) &&
                                                                    pars[1].ParameterType == typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(args[0], args[1])
                                                          select x).Single();
```

that are the LINQ `Enumerable.Any()` and `Enumerable.Select()`

and given your

```
// txreq => ((txreq.IsDeleted == False) AndAlso txreq.OLifE.Holding.Select(h => h.Policy).Any(p => p.RequirementInfo.Any(r => (r.ReqStatus.tc == OLI_LU_REQSTAT.OLI_REQSTAT_OUTSTANDING.tc))))
string str1 = filter.ToString();
```

to make a comparison of your expression with a generated expression

with some shortcuts (instead of `txreq.IsDeleted == False` I use `!rxreq.IsDeleted` and instead of including `OLI_LU_REQSTAT.OLI_REQSTAT_OUTSTANDING.tc` I read its value when the expression tree is built and put it in an `Expression.Constant()`,

```
var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TXLifeRequest), "txreq");

// txreq.IsDeleted == false (simplified to !txreq.IsDeleted)
var notIsDeleted = Expression.Not(Expression.Property(par, "IsDeleted"));

// r => 
var par4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(RequirementInfo), "r");

// OLI_LU_REQSTAT.OLI_REQSTAT_OUTSTANDING.tc
var oli_reqstat_outstanding_tc = Expression.Constant(OLI_LU_REQSTAT.OLI_REQSTAT_OUTSTANDING.tc);

// r.ReqStatus.tc == OLI_LU_REQSTAT.OLI_REQSTAT_OUTSTANDING.tc
Expression<Func<RequirementInfo, bool>> any2Lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<RequirementInfo, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(Expression.Property(par4, "ReqStatus"), "tc"), oli_reqstat_outstanding_tc), par4);

// To check if it is correct
//any2Lambda.Compile();

// p => 
var par3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Policy), "p");

// p.RequirementInfo.Any(...)
Expression<Func<Policy, bool>> any1Lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Policy, bool>>(Expression.Call(anyTSource.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(RequirementInfo)), Expression.Property(par3, "RequirementInfo"), any2Lambda), par3);

// To check if it is correct
//any1Lambda.Compile();

// h => 
var par2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Holding), "h");

// h.Policy
Expression<Func<Holding, Policy>> selectLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Holding, Policy>>(Expression.Property(par2, "Policy"), par2);

// To check if it is correct
//selectLambda.Compile();

//txreq.OLifE.Holding
var holding = Expression.Property(Expression.Property(par, "OLifE"), "Holding");

// txreq.OLifE.Holding.Select(...)
var select = Expression.Call(selectTSourceTResult.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Holding), typeof(Policy)), holding, selectLambda);
var any1 = Expression.Call(anyTSource.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Policy)), select, any1Lambda);

var and = Expression.AndAlso(notIsDeleted, any1);

Expression<Func<TXLifeRequest, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TXLifeRequest, bool>>(and, par);

// To check if it is correct and/or use it
//var compiled = lambda.Compile();
```

if we try `lambda.ToString()` we get:

```
txreq => (Not(txreq.IsDeleted) AndAlso txreq.OLifE.Holding.Select(h => h.Policy).Any(p => p.RequirementInfo.Any(r => (r.ReqStatus.tc == "SOMEVALUE"))))
```

that is similar enough.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing "useless" to this example.  It's a more complete example than anything i've found on MSDN.  Many thanks!