# How to use reflection to get a method with a ref keyword?

Tags: c#, reflection, ref

Yeah so I set up a little TestClass  to figure out what GetMethod would work to actually find the method Test(ref int i). But so far nothing worked.

```
[Button(nameof(Method))]
public bool whatever;

private void Test(ref int i)
{
    Debug.Log("Works");
}

private void Method()
{
    Type[] types = { typeof(int) };
    MethodInfo methodInfo = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(Test),
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static,
        null, types, null);
    Debug.Log(methodInfo);
}
```

What am I supposed to do? I couldn't find anything on the web so far (for GetMethod specifically)

Comment: hmmmmm. yeah the answer helps, but do you really think we were asking the same question? HIs questions isn't explicitly about  get method with ref/out? so just for the sake of clarity and simplicity I'd like it to stay. which of course is not for me to judge :-)

Comment: Building expressions uses reflection for basically everything. The first few words of the answer there is also the answer to your problem. So i think it is a fit.

Comment: @thehennyy The main thing is that, question is not about creating expressions which (of course)use reflectection, simply reflection.

Comment: @ChristophWolf the one line answer below contains the idea of how to do it. [`GetMethod()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wty12hw3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an overload that takes an array of argument parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mix Eser + gcores you obtain:

```
private void Test(ref int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i++;
}

private void Test2(out int i)
{
    i = 1000;
}

public void Method()
{
    Type[] types = { typeof(int).MakeByRefType() };

    MethodInfo methodInfo = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(Test), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, types, null);

    int num = 10;
    var pars = new object[] { num };
    methodInfo.Invoke(this, pars);
    Console.WriteLine(pars[0]);

    MethodInfo methodInfo2 = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(Test2), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, types, null);

    var pars2 = new object[1];
    methodInfo2.Invoke(this, pars2);
    Console.WriteLine(pars2[0]);
}
```

Note the `typeof(int).MakeByRefType()`, and the fact that the `object[]` array containing the parameters is modified by the invoked method. I've added a second example with `out` that shows that you still use `.MakeByRefType()`, only you don't need to initialize the `object[]` array with a parameter. Ah and you should use the exact `BindingFlags` you need, not throw every `BindingFlags` contained in MSDN together. Static and non-static work differently :-)

Comment: Hmm, I Used those binding flags to find every method there is, based on the given name. In the beginning I separated static and non-static. But then I realized I just have to check for .isStatic to whether or not invoke the method with an object or not. Or am I wrong? (didn't have any issue so far) (I store the methods before I invoke them to only use reflection when I really have to ;-) )

Comment: @ChristophWolf If you know that a method "must" be there, the "correct" thing is to give all the details you know to `GetMethod()`. For more complex methods that use generics I use a litte LINQ expression and `GetMethods()` (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414519/613130), the first part where I go looking for `Enumerable.Any` and `Enumerable.Select`). I normally try to protect the code non only from future changes in the signature of the method I look for but even for additional overloads that could be added

Comment: hahaha, nice! Well maybe I'm going to use that, if the needs of my users are going to be so elaborate^^ but usually I use field attributes that are very specific. The question above was an exception for an internal process. But thanks for the idea buddy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the method with specified arguments' types by calling an appropriate overload of [`GetMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wty12hw3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). To make the parameter a reference type use the code:

```
Type[] types = { typeof(int).MakeByRefType() };
```

Comment: Your idea can be part of the answer if you elaborate on it, but, imho, now your post cannot be called an answer.