# Get method with an 'in' parameter through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Imagine the following scenario, in which you would want to get the `MethodInfo` of the first method:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar(in int value)
    {
    }

    public void Bar(string value)
    {
    }
}
```

If we would now look at the output of `typeof(Foo).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)`:

```
MethodInfo[6] { [Void Bar(Int32 ByRef)], [Void Bar(System.String)], [Boolean Equals(System.Object)], [Int32 GetHashCode()], [System.Type GetType()], [System.String ToString()] }
```

You can see that the first method, the one which we want to get the `MethodInfo` of, it says `Int32 ByRef` which is not the same as the `Int32` type. I obvisously tried the following, but without any success:

```cs
typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Bar", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(int) }, null)
```

I took at a closer look at the actual parameter with the following code:

```cs
typeof(Foo).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)[0].GetParameters()[0]
```

Which outputs `[Int32& value]`, which seems like a pointer of the the value type. So is there any way to get the `Int32&` type at runtime? Something along the lines of `typeof(Int32&)`?

Comment: Did you already check one of the `GetMethod` overloads with `ParameterModifier[]`, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Type___System_Reflection_ParameterModifier___?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, actually they are only relevant when calling through `COM interop`, as the docs states. Nevertheless, they do not change anything, and the method will still return null, regardless of the value.

Comment: `in int` is syntax sugar for `ref int`, ensuring that it is not written to.  Makes no sense at all, but that's what the syntax allows.  Google takes you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429646/how-to-use-reflection-to-get-a-method-with-a-ref-keyword).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`MakeByRefType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makebyreftype?view=net-5.0):

```
Console.WriteLine(
    typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Bar", new[] { typeof(int).MakeByRefType() })
);

// prints "Void Bar(Int32 ByRef)"
```

Comment: To OP: this is necessary for `in`, `ref` and `out` parameters as they all compile down to the same thing